# Speed-up/Optimise MySQL statement - finding a new row that hasn't been selected before

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

First a bit of background about the tables & DB.

I have a MySQL db with a few tables in:

films:
Contains all film/series info with netflixid as a unique primary key.

users:
Contains user info "ratingid" is a unique primary key

rating:
Contains ALL user rating info, netflixid and a unique primary key of a compound "netflixid-userid"

This statement works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM films 
WHERE 
    INSTR(countrylist, 'GB') 
    AND films.netflixid NOT IN (SELECT netflixid FROM rating WHERE rating.userid = 1) 
LIMIT 1
```

but it takes longer and longer to retrieve a new film record that you haven't rated. (currently at 6.8 seconds for around 2400 user ratings on an 8000 row film table)

First I thought it was the INSTR(countrylist, 'GB'), so I split them out into their own tinyint columns - made no difference.
I have tried NOT EXISTS as well, but the times are similar.

Any thoughts/ideas on how to select a new "unrated" row from films quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd consider a separate film/country table (and avoid lists and INSTR.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just joining?

```
SELECT * 
FROM films
LEFT JOIN rating on rating.ratingid=CONCAT(films.netflixid,'-',1)
WHERE 
    INSTR(countrylist, 'GB')
    AND rating.pk IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Or doing the equivalent NOT EXISTS.

Comment: This is a good start! 5.8s to run this!
rating.pk should be rating.ratingid for my scenario

Comment: how does it do for a user with no ratings?  it really shouldn't be so slow unless your server is very underpowered.

Comment: it's about 2.3 seconds for a low rating user - my host is a bit underpowered currently, I'm probably going to upgrade it so it has a bit more "grunt"

Comment: what percentage of the films have country GB?  was the 6000 films the total number or the number of GB films?

Comment: the "right" way to do that is to have a film_country table with one row per country per film

Comment: yes, the countrylist has a list of all countries where it's available - approx 6000 have GB
Unfortunately, the data isn't great and it's coming from a 3rd party API and the data has to be pulled regularly - so I have to work with what I'm given!
It's much faster now - so thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select *
from films f
where 
    instr(countrylist, 'GB')
    and not exists (
        select 1 from rating r where r.userid = 1 and f.netflixid  = r.netflixid 
    )
```

This should take advantage of the primary key index of the `rating` table, so the subquery executes quickly.

That said, the `instr()` function in the outer query also represents a bottleneck. The database cannot take advantage of an index here, because of the function call: basically it needs to apply the computation to the whole table before it is able to filter. To avoid this, you would probably need to review your design: that is, have a separate table to represent the relationship between movies and countries, which each tuple on a separate row; then, you could use another `exists` subquery to filter on the country.

Comment: Tried this - 7.5s to complete currently.
I have the countrycode field split out into it's own tinyint field, so replacing the INSTR for "GB=1" doesn't make any difference on speed!

Comment: Tried this:
`
select *
from films f
where 
    instr(countrylist, 'GB')
    and not exists (
        select 1 from rating r where r.userid = 1 and f.netflixid  = r.netflixid 
    ) LIMIT 1
`
Result:
(1 total, Query took 7.0784 seconds.)

Comment: @PeterTurner . . . This should have the best performance.  I don't think you have correctly described the primary key on `ratings`.

Answer (score 0):

The `INSTR(countrylist, 'GB')` could be changed on `countrylist = 'GB'` or `countrylist LIKE '%GB%'` if the countrylist contains more than the country.

Then don't select all '*' if you need only some columns details. Depends on the number of columns, the query could be really slow

Comment: Tried splitting the countrylist out into separate tinyint fields - when querying I have used "GB=1" but it still takes as long!

Comment: Or the join look a nice solution:
`SELECT * 
FROM rating 
left join films on films.netflixid = rating.netflixid
WHERE 
    films.countrylist = 'GB' AND
    AND films.netflixid IS NULL
LIMIT 1`